Ltac with explicit constructor not working
I'm trying to do very simple reasoning about paths (e.g. in graphs) that are defined like follows:
Parameter Edge: nat -> nat -> Prop.

Inductive Path: nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | path_refl: forall v, Path v v.
  | path_left: forall u v w, Edge u v -> Path v w -> Path u w.

Now I want to automate simple proofs using Ltac. However, when I try the following:
Ltac autopath :=
 match goal with
  | [ _: Edge ?u ?v |- Path ?u ?v ] => constructor 2 with (v:=v); [assumption | constructor]
 end.

Lemma simple_path: forall u v, Edge u v -> Path u v.
Proof.
  intros. autopath. (* this works *)
Qed.

Lemma path_right : forall u v w, Path u v -> Edge v w -> Path u w.
Proof.
  intros. induction H.
   + Fail autopath. admit.
   + ...
end.

I do not understand why in path_right, autopath fails with "No matching clauses for match." The goal and context is analogous to the goal and context in simple_path:
H0: Edge v w
----
Path v w

This should be matched by the Ltac, but it isn't. If I change the Ltac into econstructor 2; [eassumption | constructor], it works again!
Also, if I change the Ltac into constructor 2 with v (instead of with (v:=v)), it also works!
So there seems to be something about named bindings or existentials that I do not know or understand.
So why does the Ltac work in the first lemma but not in the second, and why is it fixed when using econstructor / making the named binding unnamed?

The issue seems to come from shadowing issues: if you replace ?u and ?v with ?x and ?y in your tactic, then autopath does work in your second example.
Ltac has heuristics to try and guess which identifier refer to what, and it seems in this case it is failing at making the right choice.
Is there a particular reason for you to avoid using econstructor? Relying on evars is usually a good alternative to explicitly naming things.

Thanks, I will probably just use econstructor. No particular reason for avoiding it, I was just curious why it didn't work as expected without.
